# Где хранить secret если на клиенте и api нельзя

Tags: rest

Все привет. Долго штрудирую тему авторизации в рест апи по токенам и почти понял все кроме пары вещей. Одна из них изложена ниже.

У меня есть схема в которой есть

- клиент - некий сайт, на котором есть возможноть дернуть некий функционал с сервера с rest api.
- сервер авторизации - проверяет валиден ли пользователь и дает новый токен, когда истек предыдущий
- api сервер - получает от клиента токен, данные, проверяет токен, и если он валидный то выполняет действия над данными

Для того чтобы на сервере api расшифровать токен и проверить валиден ли он, нужно иметь secret которым подписан токен.

secret я сохраняю в redis на сервере авторизации в формате `<email>:<secret>`.

На клиенте его нельзя хранить(если верить умным людям в инетернете), так как это риски безопасности.

На сервере api его нельзя хранить, так как это нарушает один из принципов rest(не хранить состояние).

Отсюда вопрос, где хранить secret, чтобы не в postgres, не на api сервере, не на клиенте, не делать лишних запросов с api на authorization сервер за secret-ом.

Вообще считается ли хранение secret в redis на сервере api(именно на той же физической машине где и api сервер) хранением состояния? Или это не хранение состояния так как не связано с кодом?

Comment: вроде все понятно, но почему не в БД (как я понял postgres)?

Comment: Если я ничего не путаю, [секрет обычно один общий на всех пользователей](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112014) — то есть это не состояние, а параметр конфигурации, который соответственно можно записать в файл конфигурации

Comment: @Dmitry чтобы не нагружат его лишний раз

Comment: @Quester может я чего не правильно делаю, используя `dajngo-rest-framework` и еще пару rest решений, из коробки всегда токены в базу летят. Посижу, почитаю, может кто напишет "как правильно".

Comment: @Dmitry токены в базе — это лишнее занятое место и лишняя нагрузка на сервер. Поэтому умные люди изобрели JWT, который не требует ходить в базу и позволяет ничего не хранить (кроме секрета)

Comment: @andreymal если я правильно понял, то на authorization сервере я могу в конфиге прописать secret который будет подписывать все токены, а на сервере api я также прописываю в конфиге secret который будет  расшифровывать все токены?

Comment: @Quester да. (Кстати, не смешивайте подпись и шифрование, это разные вещи)

Comment: @andreymal что это значит? Как их смешать? Или не смешать)

Comment: когда найдете решение, напишите ответ. Сомнения по поводу моих проектов, спать мешает)

Comment: @Dmitry я сделал один серкрет для всех в yaml файле конфига сервера, теперь осталось только придумать из чего его сгенерировать). А вы смотрели в базе, после того как django кладет туда секрет, там не одинаковые ли значения для всех? И что в документации к фреймворку? как он вообще ключ создает, какими алгоритмами и из чего?

Comment: @Quester django и django-rest-framework не используют секрет, а генерируют токены просто из случайных букв и цифр

Comment: @andreymal а, затем кладет их базу и потом каждый раз бегает в базу чтобы проверить валиден ли?

Comment: @Quester да. Несмотря на "лишнюю нагрузку", для небольших сайтов это работает вполне нормально

Comment: Нашли решение? я смотрю у меня не все в порядке в этом смысле

Comment: @Dmitry ну да, я там выше в комментах написал. Один секрет в конфиге сервера)